# Laravel select count in raw query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, count

I need to get count using `Eloquent` in `Laravel`. My query:

```
$sqlQueryCount = " SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM client_order co 
        INNER JOIN client c ON c.id = co.client_id
        LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = co.user_id
        WHERE co.user_id = ?
         ";
        
       $resultCount = DB::select($sqlQueryCount,
            [$userId])->count();
```

It doesn't work, cannot use `count()` on array.

Comment: I never run a complete query like that on Laravel. But you said that `select` is returning an `array` (because when you do `->count` it throws that error. So I think you need to do 2 small changes, first add a name to the `count`, for example `COUNT(*) AS total` or something like that, then remove `->count()` and after running `select`, in a new line, do `$resultCount['total']` or the name you decided to use. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
DB::table('client_order')
        ->join('client ', 'client.id', '=', 'client_order.client_id')
        ->leftJoin('user ', 'user.id', '=', 'client_order.user_id')
        ->where('client_order.user_id',$user->id)->count();
```